# Swift iOS not sure if app or remote server should handle amazon s3

Tags: java, ios, swift, backend

For my app I store/receive images from amazon s3. In the desktop client my API/server handles the file upload or download.

But now I wonder if I should do the same when it comes to my iOS app?

Should I download the S3 sdk for the iOS and make my phone scale/upload the images to amazon s3 / making api calls to S3 in order to get the image urls?

Or should I first send the images from the phone to the server. Then let the server/backend scale and upload the images to S3 / let my server send the images urls to the iOS app?

Comment: Let the server do all the work and just send back the URLs. It keeps the client lightweight and you won't have to reimplement functionality on every supported platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, keep your client as dumb as possible. If you already have this functionality on your server, you don't want to re-implement it.